# How to keep sound off while transitioning between SKScenes

Tags: swift

I created this game in Sprite Kit and I give the user the ability to mute the sound by pressing a button before they can tap and start the game. However, when it is game over and the GameOverScene appears, the music still stays muted. When a new GameScene is called the music however will start playing again. Anyone know how to solve this issue. This is the code I have for my music.

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
    filename, withExtension: nil)
if (url == nil) {
    println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
    return
}

var error: NSError? = nil
backgroundMusicPlayer =
    AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
    println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
    return
}

backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    muteSound.name = "muteSound"
    muteSound.position.x = view.center.x
    muteSound.position.y = view.center.y + 100
    self.addChild(muteSound)

    playBackgroundMusic("Box Office.mp3")

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "muteSound" {
            backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not muting the sound but stopping it, also there's no code here to resume or play the sound on gameover.

Comment: So how can I keep the sound stopped if the user presses the muteSound button? And with this I mean, even when a new scene is presented..

Comment: keep a global variable Bool somewhere and set it to true/false when the button is pressed. Then when you play the sound check if that variable is tru and don't play the sound if it is.